# What do I do with a narrowboat?

Tags: single-word-requests

We were discussing the prospect of messing about on the canals yesterday, and I happened to mention that I had spent quite a bit of time, er, doing what exactly with the narrowboat?

I wasn't really *[driving](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/drive)* it

> To guide, control, or direct (a vehicle).

but to say I was *[sailing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sail)* it

> To navigate or manage (a vessel).

when the watercourse is narrower than the narrowboat is long seems to be stretching it a bit. Were the boat in a tunnel I might be *[legging](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leg)* it

> (v. tr.) Obsolete to propel (a canal boat) through a tunnel by lying on one's back and walking one's feet along the tunnel roof

but fortunately narrowboats nowadays are usually equipped with an engine.

So, does anyone know what I am doing while in command of a narrowboat?

Comment: Were you perhaps *steering* it?

Comment: In US sailing parlance, the person controlling the boat (working the tiller or wheel) is often referred to as *driving* it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely one navigates a narrowboat

Comment: I agree 'navigate' is the best word. It involves far more than 'driving', and 'steering', and sailing doesn't enter into the question. I don't think 'skipper' is right either, since it implies being in charge of others, and you may be the only crew member. You see, navigating a narrow boat involves knowing how to use locks, and being strong enough to turn the machinery. In the old days there was also a horse to control, which pulled the boat along from the 'tow-path'.

Answer (score 1):

You skipper it.

> To act as skipper or captain of (a vessel, team, etc.) (OED)

Answer (score 1):

You *cruise* in a narrowboat.

> The good weather encouraged more boat movements than usual at this time of year, with the fair weather boaters out **cruising,** taking advantage of the conditions.
>
> ... it is best to let the blood sport fanatics rant their heads off, while you **cruise** by.
>
> I have **cruised** many miles ...
>
> [Narrowboat World](http://www.narrowboatworld.com/index.php/brian-holmes/6387-news-from-the-fensoctober) *(all my emphasis)*

Comment: From same source: _as well as piloting them_ --- *where you steer your own boat*

Comment: Personally I would steer clear of "cruising" as it has slang conotations

Answer (score 1):

If it has sails you sail it, if not you can

- pilot it
- captain it
- operate it
- steer it

But I am sure a LOT of non-sail boat pilots would say ***sail*** it